# Spring WebSockets for multiple topics

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket

I am building a web console that will be used to monitor the progress of an ongoing tasks of processing for multiple files and my requirement is to have a realtime updates for each and every file separatly (based on user request) via Web-sockets, so the user will typically login and select the file he want to see the progress on and will be re-directed to a page with live updates from the system about this file so typically I will need a different topic to be created every time based on user request with my scheduled job running on the background publishing updates on each created topic.

my question is there any way to fulfill these requirement using spring WebSockets and scheduled jobs or should I switch to event bus like the one in vertx ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week of trials i ended up using vertx eventbus, it gives me exactly what i needed, it even includes a periodic timer which can be cancelled by a timer id which is exactly what i was looking for, adding the Async nature of vertx and its lightweight which makes it a perfect fit for my requirements.